# ROS and Open Vino

Tags: ros, intel, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I'm interested in running the Neural Compute Stick 2 with ROS, in Python. The first Neural Compute Stick used the NCSDK which provided Python 2.7 support. OpenVINO doesn't seem to have any plans for Python 2.7 support ([requirements](https://software.intel.com/en-us/openvino-toolkit/choose-download/free-download-linux)). I'm not particularly skillful with C code, so I'm curious if anyone else has gotten OpenVINO to work with ROS1+Python.

What are my options here? As I'm running a simulation in Unity and communicating over a ros websocket (like the LG Simulator), would [roslibpy](https://github.com/gramaziokohler/roslibpy) be a good option? I think that could be installed with python3 to connect over the rosbridge/websocket.

Note:
Confusingly it seems like there might be some 2.7 support per [here](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_inference_engine_ie_bridges_python_docs_api_overview.html)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321833/ros-and-open-vino/) by [rukie](https://answers.ros.org/users/38027/rukie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2019-04-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2019-04-25**:
@rukie Depending on what ros distro you are using (and also which packages you are using), you can potentially use Python3 in your setup with ROS 1 and not run into too much trouble. You could also try ROS 2, which requires Python 3.

**Comment by [rukie](https://answers.ros.org/users/38027/rukie/) on 2019-04-25**:
@allenh1 I'm using ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04. Which ROS version would have the best Python3 support? I assume Melodic?

I previously stuck with Kinetic because it appears to have best support for online tutorials (and it seems like Indigo is in all the books). Though I'm getting to a point that I'm not so reliant on existing packages and tutorials.

**Comment by [rukie](https://answers.ros.org/users/38027/rukie/) on 2019-04-25**:
I'll say this doesn't look particularly fun.
https://medium.com/@beta_b0t/how-to-setup-ros-with-python-3-44a69ca36674

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-25**:
@rukie: the blog documents 3 steps, 1 of which is optional (the `rostest` one) and gives the exact commands.

**Comment by [rukie](https://answers.ros.org/users/38027/rukie/) on 2019-04-25**:
And I assume all of these apt packages should be ignored?

python3-catkin-pkg python3-catkin-pkg-modules python3-dateutil python3-docutils python3-pygments python3-pyparsing python3-roman python3-rosdep python3-rosdistro python3-rosdistro-modules
python3-rospkg python3-rospkg-modules

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2019-04-25**:
I'm not sure what you mean by "ignored" here... If you mean "not installed" then no, you probably need them.

**Comment by [rukie](https://answers.ros.org/users/38027/rukie/) on 2019-04-25**:
@allenh1
If I try to install a python3-catkin-pkg it wants to uninstall *all* of ros-melodic. I don't understand how those packages might play into a ROS and Python3 environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written a easy-to-use ROS wrapper for OpenVINO R3 Inference Engine, with a step-by-step instruction! =) https://github.com/songshan0321/ros_vino

---

Originally posted by [songshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/39672/songshan/) with karma: 36 on 2019-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2